# What is the complete version of the paper: "How to Generate and Exchange Secrets (extended abstract)" by Andrew Yao?

Tags: reference-request, cryptography, security

I've found numerous places that claim that the paper "How to Generate and Exchange Secrets" by Andrew Yao introduces garbled circuits as a solution to the secure multiparty computation problem. However, I can only seem to locate the extended abstract which lacks proofs and does not seem to mention garbled circuits. It only appears to define useful properties for solving the problem and state several theorems without proof. A complete version of the paper is mentioned at the end of this extended abstract, but I cannot locate it. Is the complete version under a different name?

I have already found expositions that explain garbled circuits. At this point I am interested in finding the complete paper, if possible.

Comment: Is your goal to find the full paper, or to learn the ideas of Yao's garbled circuits construction?  If the latter, there are *lots* of expositions of it (in cryptography lecture notes, textbooks, more recent papers).  Which are you looking for?

Comment: I have found expositions that explain garbled circuits, but I am also interested in finding the complete paper.

Comment: Complete versions don't always exist. If you can't find it, it's probably not there.

Comment: Thanks Yuval, that's what I was starting to suspect. I figured since this is a fairly famous paper, someone must know conclusively whether or not the full version exists.

Comment: On Yao's DBLP page I can't find a paper after 1986 with a remotely similar name.  So I suspect it doesn't exist.  http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/pers/hd/y/Yao:Andrew_Chi=Chih

Comment: Interesting.  In the _bibliography_ of the Turing award page it says that garbled circuits were only implicit in the paper, and that he only introduced them explicitly in the talk he gave at the conference. http://amturing.acm.org/bib/yao_1611524.cfm#bib_6

Comment: Thanks, the bibliography seems to imply that the complete paper doesn't exist. Thanks Wandering Logic, now I know the answer.

Comment: Please five a full reference; it may be important for a question like this.

Answer (score 1):

Garbled circuits were only implied by the extended abstract. They were only explicitly introduced in the talk given by Andrew Yao at the conference.

This is clear from a footnote on the Turing Award Page:

> The first of these two papers introduces secure function evaluation, and gives a > protocol for the famous Millionaires’ Problem. In talks related to these papers > Yao introduced a technique for secure computation known as garbled circuits.

which may be found here: http://amturing.acm.org/bib/yao_1611524.cfm#bib_6

Credit is due to [Wandering Logic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/7459/wandering-logic) for giving this very helpful answer in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia now has a brief survey of the history of garbled circuits with reference to published materials:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbled_circuit